# Change MSRP text in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configuration, translate, msrp

I want to translate msrp `config.xml` file. Here is the image.

[image]

I found that this text is in `/vendor/magento/module-msrp/etc/config.xml` but it is not **translatable**. How can I **override** this `config.xml` to translate this text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can traslate the text by add translation text to

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/i18n/en_US.csv
```

For Example

"**en_US.csv**","**YourText**"

After add run bellow commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I tried that, but text is not translatable, so it won't be translated. Thanks for answer.